# Constricting variables in NMinimize to binary (0,1) value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to optimize a large function with 1024 input variables using NMinimize. The caveat is, that the function should only be called with each of the variables as a binary value (0 or 1). The function evaluates with values other than 0 or 1, however it does not have a reasonable/physical meaning doing so.
For context, the function describes the optical properties of a material structure with a parameterized geometry, where the 1024 binary input variables parameterize the geometry space.

I have tried the following:

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
Testfunction[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := x1^2 - x2 + (1 - x3)^2 + x4
```

It's obvious that the correct solution for the minimum of the above function with the binary constraints is x1=0, x2=1,x3=1,x4=0.

I tried using NMinimize as shown below and to use StepMonitor to figure out what values the minimizer tests:

```
testprogress = {};
testopt = NMinimize[{Hold[Testfunction[x1, x2, x3, x4]],
   vars \[Element] Integers &&
    vars < 2 &&
    vars > -1
   }
  , vars, MaxIterations -> 20, 
  StepMonitor :> AppendTo[testprogress, vars]]
```

This gives the right answer `{-1., {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, x4 -> 0}}`

HOWEVER, when looking into the data appended to `testprogress`I find that real numbers rather than (0,1) where used to find the solution.

```
In[283]:= testprogress

Out[283]= {{0.458386, 0.630475, 0.540562, 0.0205422}, {0.420176, 
  0.71166, 0.723082, 0.349868}, {0.420176, 0.955819, 0.564741, 
  0.286847}, {0.289378, 0.737188, 0.518322, 0.275842}, {0.289378, 
  0.737188, 0.518322, 0.275842}, {0.420775, 0.518111, 0.549715, 
  0.245677}, {0.22129, 0.595524, 0.745492, 0.295513}, {0.22129, 
  0.595524, 0.745492, 0.295513}, {0.22129, 0.595524, 0.643158, 
  0.295513}, {0.22129, 0.690378, 0.830813, 0.295513}, {0.22129, 
  0.762992, 0.830813, 0.295513}, {0.22129, 0.762992, 0.830813, 
  0.295513}, {0.277562, 0.915617, 0.992179, 0.295513}, {0.277562, 
  0.790024, 0.957812, 0.295513}, {0.277562, 0.790024, 0.957812, 
  0.0807183}, {0.277562, 0.790024, 0.541769, 0.370714}, {0.0588165, 
  0.788637, 0.993765, 0.370714}, {0.00163245, 0.788637, 0.91337, 
  0.370714}, {0.39818, 0.788637, 0.985537, 0.370714}, {0.156202, 
  0.516489, 0.985537, 0.226041}}
```

it seems to me that the solution provided is simply the last step in `testprogress`rounded.

Can I modify the behaviour of NMinimize to only test using 0 and 1 for the minimization? Are there other optimization routines in Mathematica that would allow to do so? Given the large (2^1024) space to search and the fact that the function evaluates to meaningless values when non-binary values are used it seems to me that I have to prevent searches with values other than 0 and 1 to find the optimum solution.

EDIT:

Thank you all for the input. I tried a combination of your solutions and still find perplexing behavior.

1. it seems that while NMinimize allows combining variables in a vector to set constraints like I did `0>=vars<=1` , it shows different behavior in the step monitor option. Combining the advice I tried:

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
testfunction[x1 : 0 | 1, x2 : 0 | 1, x3 : 0 | 1, x4 : 0 | 1] = 
  x1^2 - x2 + (1 - x3)^2 + x4;
testopt = 
 Reap[NMinimize[{Hold[testfunction[x1, x2, x3, x4]], 
    vars \[Element] Integers && vars <= 1 && vars >= 0}, vars, 
   MaxIterations -> 5, StepMonitor :> Sow[vars]]]
```

which yields

```
{{-1., {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, 
   x4 -> 0}}, {{{0.458386, 0.630475, 0.540562, 0.0205422}, {0.420176, 
    0.71166, 0.723082, 0.349868}, {0.420176, 0.955819, 0.564741, 
    0.286847}, {0.289378, 0.737188, 0.518322, 0.275842}, {0.289378, 
    0.737188, 0.518322, 0.275842}}}}
```

and

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
testfunction[x1 : 0 | 1, x2 : 0 | 1, x3 : 0 | 1, x4 : 0 | 1] = 
  x1^2 - x2 + (1 - x3)^2 + x4;
testopt = 
 Reap[NMinimize[{Hold[testfunction[x1, x2, x3, x4]], 
    vars \[Element] Integers && vars <= 1 && vars >= 0}, vars, 
   MaxIterations -> 5, StepMonitor :> Sow[{x1, x2, x3, x4}]]]
```

which gives

```
{{-1., {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 1, x3 -> 1, 
   x4 -> 0}}, {{{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 
    0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}}}
```

What is the real numbered data sowed when using `StepMonitor :> Sow[vars]`? Roman is right that the function `testfunction[x1 : 0 | 1, x2 : 0 | 1, x3 : 0 | 1, x4 : 0 | 1]` cannot be evaluated with non-integers.

```
In[69]:= testfunction[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]

Out[69]= testfunction[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
```

Are the values stored when using `StepMonitor :> Sow[vars]` some internal numbers that are not actually used to evaluate `testfunction` like I think Daniel is hinting towards?

Comment: If you replace your `StepMonitor :> AppendTo[testprogress, vars]` with `StepMonitor :> Sow[vars]` you'll get much better performance. [See here for a tutorial.](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EvaluationOfExpressions.html#8044)

Comment: If you define your binary function as `testfunction[x1 : 0 | 1, x2 : 0 | 1, x3 : 0 | 1, x4 : 0 | 1] = x1^2 - x2 + (1 - x3)^2 + x4`, then you'll be sure that it can never be called with any arguments other than `0` or `1`.

Comment: (1) Internal code is likely treating the values as integers by rounding before use in evaluating the objective function. The reason they are not generated as integers is that it is difficult to generate new values as integers for several methods used by `NMinimize`. (2) One common way to impose the restriction is to have constraints of the form `0<=x<=1` and `Element[x,Integers]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is an "answer" to what you ask, but when I use

```
testprogress = {};
testopt = 
  NMinimize[{Hold[Testfunction[x1, x2, x3, x4]], 
    0 <= x1 <= 1 && 0 <= x2 <= 1 && 0 <= x3 <= 1 && 0 <= x4 <= 1 && 
     x1 \[Element] Integers && x2 \[Element] Integers && 
     x3 \[Element] Integers && x4 \[Element] Integers}, {x1, x2, x3, 
    x4}, MaxIterations -> 20, 
   StepMonitor :> AppendTo[testprogress, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]]
```

I see what I think you are expecting.  That is, the reported variables are integers.  In other words, the test progress is

```
(* {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 
   0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 
   1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 
   1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 
   0}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}*)
```

Comment: Yes, the `StepMonitor` is a bit finicky and you have to write out `{x1, x2, x3, x4}` as an argument there instead of using `vars`. This has to do with [lexical scoping](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html), as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

First of all an essential tip: Reduce all powers of x[i]^j to simple x[i], since that's the same for only 0 or 1 and it saves a factor of 10.000 of time.

Here an example:

```
vars = Array[x, 1024];
tf = Table[(RandomInteger[{2, 4}] + (-1)^RandomInteger[] vars[[i]])^
       RandomInteger[{1, 3}], {i, vars // Length}] // Total;

tf2 = Expand[tf] /. x[aa_]^bb_ -> x[aa];

th1 = Thread[0 <= vars <= 1];
th2 = Thread[# \[Element] Integers] & /@ vars;

c = 0; {testopt = 
        NMinimize[{tf2, Join[th1, th2]}, vars, StepMonitor :> c++], 
c} // Timing
```

.

```
{0.015, {{11223., {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 1, x[4] -> 1, 
x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 1, x[7] -> 1, x[8] -> 0, x[9] -> 0, x[10] -> 1,
 x[11] -> 1, x[12] -> 0, x[13] -> 1, x[14] -> 1, x[15] -> 0, 
x[16] -> 1, x[17] -> 0, x[18] -> 1, x[19] -> 0, x[20] -> 0, 
x[21] -> 1, x[22] -> 1, x[23] -> 1, x[24] -> 1, x[25] -> 0, 
x[26] -> 0, x[27] -> 0, x[28] -> 0, x[29] -> 0, x[30] -> 1, 
x[31] -> 1, x[32] -> 0, x[33] -> 0, x[34] -> 0, x[35] -> 1, 
x[36] -> 1, x[37] -> 0, x[38] -> 0, x[39] -> 0, x[40] -> 0, 
x[41] -> 0, x[42] -> 1, x[43] -> 1, x[44] -> 0, x[45] -> 1, 
x[46] -> 0, x[47] -> 1, x[48] -> 0, x[49] -> 0, x[50] -> 1, 
x[51] -> 1, x[52] -> 0, x[53] -> 1, x[54] -> 1, x[55] -> 0, 
x[56] -> 1, x[57] -> 1, x[58] -> 1, x[59] -> 0, x[60] -> 0, 
x[61] -> 0, x[62] -> 0, x[63] -> 0, x[64] -> 0, x[65] -> 1, 
x[66] -> 0, x[67] -> 0, x[68] -> 1, x[69] -> 1, x[70] -> 0, 
x[71] -> 0, x[72] -> 1, x[73] -> 0, x[74] -> 0, x[75] -> 0, 
x[76] -> 1, x[77] -> 0, x[78] -> 0, x[79] -> 0, x[80] -> 0, 
x[81] -> 0, x[82] -> 0, x[83] -> 0, x[84] -> 1, x[85] -> 0, 
x[86] -> 0, x[87] -> 1, x[88] -> 1, x[89] -> 0, x[90] -> 1, 
x[91] -> 1, x[92] -> 0, x[93] -> 1, x[94] -> 0, x[95] -> 1, 
x[96] -> 1, x[97] -> 1, x[98] -> 0, x[99] -> 0, x[100] -> 0, 
x[101] -> 0, x[102] -> 0, x[103] -> 0, x[104] -> 0, x[105] -> 0, 
x[106] -> 1, x[107] -> 1, x[108] -> 1, x[109] -> 0, x[110] -> 1, 
x[111] -> 1, x[112] -> 1, x[113] -> 1, x[114] -> 0, x[115] -> 1, 
x[116] -> 0, x[117] -> 0, x[118] -> 1, x[119] -> 0, x[120] -> 0, 
x[121] -> 1, x[122] -> 1, x[123] -> 1, x[124] -> 0, x[125] -> 0, 
x[126] -> 0, x[127] -> 1, x[128] -> 1, x[129] -> 0, x[130] -> 0, 
x[131] -> 0, x[132] -> 0, x[133] -> 0, x[134] -> 0, x[135] -> 1, 
x[136] -> 0, x[137] -> 0, x[138] -> 1, x[139] -> 0, x[140] -> 1, 
x[141] -> 1, x[142] -> 0, x[143] -> 1, x[144] -> 1, x[145] -> 1, 
x[146] -> 0, x[147] -> 1, x[148] -> 0, x[149] -> 1, x[150] -> 1, 
x[151] -> 1, x[152] -> 0, x[153] -> 1, x[154] -> 1, x[155] -> 0, 
x[156] -> 0, x[157] -> 0, x[158] -> 1, x[159] -> 1, x[160] -> 1, 
x[161] -> 0, x[162] -> 0, x[163] -> 1, x[164] -> 0, x[165] -> 0, 
x[166] -> 1, x[167] -> 0, x[168] -> 1, x[169] -> 0, x[170] -> 1, 
x[171] -> 1, x[172] -> 1, x[173] -> 1, x[174] -> 0, x[175] -> 1, 
x[176] -> 1, x[177] -> 1, x[178] -> 1, x[179] -> 0, x[180] -> 0, 
x[181] -> 1, x[182] -> 1, x[183] -> 0, x[184] -> 0, x[185] -> 0, 
x[186] -> 0, x[187] -> 1, x[188] -> 1, x[189] -> 0, x[190] -> 1, 
x[191] -> 0, x[192] -> 1, x[193] -> 1, x[194] -> 0, x[195] -> 1, 
x[196] -> 0, x[197] -> 1, x[198] -> 1, x[199] -> 1, x[200] -> 1, 
x[201] -> 1, x[202] -> 1, x[203] -> 0, x[204] -> 1, x[205] -> 1, 
x[206] -> 1, x[207] -> 0, x[208] -> 0, x[209] -> 0, x[210] -> 1, 
x[211] -> 0, x[212] -> 0, x[213] -> 0, x[214] -> 1, x[215] -> 0, 
x[216] -> 1, x[217] -> 1, x[218] -> 0, x[219] -> 0, x[220] -> 0, 
x[221] -> 1, x[222] -> 0, x[223] -> 1, x[224] -> 1, x[225] -> 1, 
x[226] -> 1, x[227] -> 0, x[228] -> 1, x[229] -> 1, x[230] -> 1, 
x[231] -> 0, x[232] -> 1, x[233] -> 0, x[234] -> 1, x[235] -> 0, 
x[236] -> 1, x[237] -> 1, x[238] -> 1, x[239] -> 0, x[240] -> 1, 
x[241] -> 1, x[242] -> 1, x[243] -> 1, x[244] -> 1, x[245] -> 0, 
x[246] -> 1, x[247] -> 1, x[248] -> 1, x[249] -> 0, x[250] -> 1, 
x[251] -> 1, x[252] -> 1, x[253] -> 0, x[254] -> 0, x[255] -> 0, 
x[256] -> 1, x[257] -> 0, x[258] -> 1, x[259] -> 0, x[260] -> 0, 
x[261] -> 0, x[262] -> 1, x[263] -> 0, x[264] -> 0, x[265] -> 0, 
x[266] -> 1, x[267] -> 1, x[268] -> 0, x[269] -> 1, x[270] -> 1, 
x[271] -> 0, x[272] -> 1, x[273] -> 0, x[274] -> 1, x[275] -> 0, 
x[276] -> 1, x[277] -> 0, x[278] -> 0, x[279] -> 0, x[280] -> 0, 
x[281] -> 0, x[282] -> 0, x[283] -> 0, x[284] -> 1, x[285] -> 0, 
x[286] -> 0, x[287] -> 1, x[288] -> 1, x[289] -> 0, x[290] -> 1, 
x[291] -> 1, x[292] -> 1, x[293] -> 1, x[294] -> 1, x[295] -> 1, 
x[296] -> 0, x[297] -> 1, x[298] -> 0, x[299] -> 1, x[300] -> 0, 
x[301] -> 1, x[302] -> 1, x[303] -> 0, x[304] -> 0, x[305] -> 0, 
x[306] -> 1, x[307] -> 1, x[308] -> 1, x[309] -> 0, x[310] -> 0, 
x[311] -> 1, x[312] -> 1, x[313] -> 0, x[314] -> 1, x[315] -> 0, 
x[316] -> 1, x[317] -> 0, x[318] -> 0, x[319] -> 0, x[320] -> 0, 
x[321] -> 1, x[322] -> 1, x[323] -> 1, x[324] -> 0, x[325] -> 1, 
x[326] -> 1, x[327] -> 0, x[328] -> 0, x[329] -> 1, x[330] -> 1, 
x[331] -> 1, x[332] -> 1, x[333] -> 0, x[334] -> 0, x[335] -> 0, 
x[336] -> 1, x[337] -> 0, x[338] -> 0, x[339] -> 1, x[340] -> 0, 
x[341] -> 0, x[342] -> 0, x[343] -> 1, x[344] -> 1, x[345] -> 1, 
x[346] -> 1, x[347] -> 0, x[348] -> 1, x[349] -> 1, x[350] -> 0, 
x[351] -> 0, x[352] -> 1, x[353] -> 1, x[354] -> 0, x[355] -> 0, 
x[356] -> 0, x[357] -> 1, x[358] -> 0, x[359] -> 1, x[360] -> 0, 
x[361] -> 0, x[362] -> 0, x[363] -> 0, x[364] -> 0, x[365] -> 0, 
x[366] -> 1, x[367] -> 1, x[368] -> 1, x[369] -> 0, x[370] -> 0, 
x[371] -> 0, x[372] -> 0, x[373] -> 0, x[374] -> 1, x[375] -> 1, 
x[376] -> 1, x[377] -> 1, x[378] -> 0, x[379] -> 0, x[380] -> 1, 
x[381] -> 0, x[382] -> 0, x[383] -> 1, x[384] -> 1, x[385] -> 0, 
x[386] -> 0, x[387] -> 0, x[388] -> 0, x[389] -> 0, x[390] -> 1, 
x[391] -> 0, x[392] -> 1, x[393] -> 0, x[394] -> 1, x[395] -> 0, 
x[396] -> 1, x[397] -> 1, x[398] -> 1, x[399] -> 0, x[400] -> 1, 
x[401] -> 0, x[402] -> 1, x[403] -> 1, x[404] -> 0, x[405] -> 0, 
x[406] -> 1, x[407] -> 1, x[408] -> 0, x[409] -> 0, x[410] -> 1, 
x[411] -> 0, x[412] -> 1, x[413] -> 0, x[414] -> 1, x[415] -> 0, 
x[416] -> 0, x[417] -> 0, x[418] -> 1, x[419] -> 1, x[420] -> 0, 
x[421] -> 0, x[422] -> 1, x[423] -> 1, x[424] -> 1, x[425] -> 0, 
x[426] -> 1, x[427] -> 0, x[428] -> 0, x[429] -> 0, x[430] -> 1, 
x[431] -> 0, x[432] -> 1, x[433] -> 0, x[434] -> 0, x[435] -> 1, 
x[436] -> 0, x[437] -> 0, x[438] -> 0, x[439] -> 0, x[440] -> 1, 
x[441] -> 1, x[442] -> 1, x[443] -> 0, x[444] -> 1, x[445] -> 0, 
x[446] -> 1, x[447] -> 1, x[448] -> 0, x[449] -> 1, x[450] -> 1, 
x[451] -> 1, x[452] -> 0, x[453] -> 0, x[454] -> 0, x[455] -> 0, 
x[456] -> 1, x[457] -> 1, x[458] -> 1, x[459] -> 0, x[460] -> 0, 
x[461] -> 1, x[462] -> 1, x[463] -> 0, x[464] -> 1, x[465] -> 1, 
x[466] -> 1, x[467] -> 0, x[468] -> 0, x[469] -> 1, x[470] -> 0, 
x[471] -> 1, x[472] -> 1, x[473] -> 1, x[474] -> 1, x[475] -> 0, 
x[476] -> 1, x[477] -> 1, x[478] -> 1, x[479] -> 1, x[480] -> 1, 
x[481] -> 0, x[482] -> 0, x[483] -> 0, x[484] -> 0, x[485] -> 0, 
x[486] -> 0, x[487] -> 0, x[488] -> 0, x[489] -> 0, x[490] -> 1, 
x[491] -> 0, x[492] -> 0, x[493] -> 0, x[494] -> 0, x[495] -> 1, 
x[496] -> 1, x[497] -> 0, x[498] -> 1, x[499] -> 1, x[500] -> 1, 
x[501] -> 1, x[502] -> 1, x[503] -> 1, x[504] -> 0, x[505] -> 0, 
x[506] -> 1, x[507] -> 1, x[508] -> 0, x[509] -> 1, x[510] -> 0, 
x[511] -> 0, x[512] -> 0, x[513] -> 1, x[514] -> 0, x[515] -> 1, 
x[516] -> 1, x[517] -> 1, x[518] -> 1, x[519] -> 0, x[520] -> 0, 
x[521] -> 0, x[522] -> 1, x[523] -> 1, x[524] -> 1, x[525] -> 1, 
x[526] -> 0, x[527] -> 0, x[528] -> 1, x[529] -> 0, x[530] -> 1, 
x[531] -> 1, x[532] -> 1, x[533] -> 0, x[534] -> 0, x[535] -> 1, 
x[536] -> 0, x[537] -> 0, x[538] -> 0, x[539] -> 1, x[540] -> 1, 
x[541] -> 0, x[542] -> 0, x[543] -> 1, x[544] -> 0, x[545] -> 1, 
x[546] -> 0, x[547] -> 1, x[548] -> 1, x[549] -> 0, x[550] -> 1, 
x[551] -> 1, x[552] -> 1, x[553] -> 1, x[554] -> 0, x[555] -> 0, 
x[556] -> 1, x[557] -> 1, x[558] -> 1, x[559] -> 0, x[560] -> 1, 
x[561] -> 0, x[562] -> 1, x[563] -> 0, x[564] -> 0, x[565] -> 0, 
x[566] -> 0, x[567] -> 0, x[568] -> 0, x[569] -> 0, x[570] -> 1, 
x[571] -> 0, x[572] -> 1, x[573] -> 0, x[574] -> 0, x[575] -> 0, 
x[576] -> 0, x[577] -> 1, x[578] -> 1, x[579] -> 1, x[580] -> 1, 
x[581] -> 1, x[582] -> 0, x[583] -> 0, x[584] -> 0, x[585] -> 0, 
x[586] -> 1, x[587] -> 0, x[588] -> 0, x[589] -> 0, x[590] -> 0, 
x[591] -> 0, x[592] -> 0, x[593] -> 1, x[594] -> 0, x[595] -> 0, 
x[596] -> 0, x[597] -> 0, x[598] -> 1, x[599] -> 1, x[600] -> 1, 
x[601] -> 1, x[602] -> 0, x[603] -> 0, x[604] -> 0, x[605] -> 1, 
x[606] -> 1, x[607] -> 0, x[608] -> 0, x[609] -> 0, x[610] -> 1, 
x[611] -> 0, x[612] -> 0, x[613] -> 0, x[614] -> 1, x[615] -> 1, 
x[616] -> 0, x[617] -> 1, x[618] -> 1, x[619] -> 1, x[620] -> 1, 
x[621] -> 1, x[622] -> 0, x[623] -> 1, x[624] -> 1, x[625] -> 0, 
x[626] -> 0, x[627] -> 0, x[628] -> 1, x[629] -> 0, x[630] -> 0, 
x[631] -> 0, x[632] -> 0, x[633] -> 1, x[634] -> 1, x[635] -> 1, 
x[636] -> 0, x[637] -> 1, x[638] -> 0, x[639] -> 0, x[640] -> 0, 
x[641] -> 1, x[642] -> 0, x[643] -> 0, x[644] -> 0, x[645] -> 1, 
x[646] -> 1, x[647] -> 0, x[648] -> 1, x[649] -> 1, x[650] -> 0, 
x[651] -> 0, x[652] -> 1, x[653] -> 1, x[654] -> 0, x[655] -> 0, 
x[656] -> 0, x[657] -> 1, x[658] -> 1, x[659] -> 0, x[660] -> 1, 
x[661] -> 1, x[662] -> 0, x[663] -> 1, x[664] -> 0, x[665] -> 1, 
x[666] -> 1, x[667] -> 1, x[668] -> 0, x[669] -> 1, x[670] -> 1, 
x[671] -> 0, x[672] -> 1, x[673] -> 0, x[674] -> 0, x[675] -> 1, 
x[676] -> 0, x[677] -> 1, x[678] -> 1, x[679] -> 0, x[680] -> 1, 
x[681] -> 1, x[682] -> 0, x[683] -> 1, x[684] -> 1, x[685] -> 1, 
x[686] -> 1, x[687] -> 0, x[688] -> 1, x[689] -> 0, x[690] -> 0, 
x[691] -> 0, x[692] -> 1, x[693] -> 0, x[694] -> 0, x[695] -> 0, 
x[696] -> 1, x[697] -> 1, x[698] -> 0, x[699] -> 1, x[700] -> 1, 
x[701] -> 1, x[702] -> 1, x[703] -> 0, x[704] -> 1, x[705] -> 0, 
x[706] -> 1, x[707] -> 1, x[708] -> 1, x[709] -> 1, x[710] -> 1, 
x[711] -> 0, x[712] -> 1, x[713] -> 0, x[714] -> 1, x[715] -> 0, 
x[716] -> 0, x[717] -> 0, x[718] -> 1, x[719] -> 0, x[720] -> 0, 
x[721] -> 1, x[722] -> 1, x[723] -> 1, x[724] -> 1, x[725] -> 1, 
x[726] -> 0, x[727] -> 0, x[728] -> 1, x[729] -> 1, x[730] -> 0, 
x[731] -> 0, x[732] -> 0, x[733] -> 0, x[734] -> 0, x[735] -> 0, 
x[736] -> 0, x[737] -> 0, x[738] -> 1, x[739] -> 1, x[740] -> 1, 
x[741] -> 1, x[742] -> 1, x[743] -> 1, x[744] -> 1, x[745] -> 0, 
x[746] -> 1, x[747] -> 0, x[748] -> 0, x[749] -> 0, x[750] -> 1, 
x[751] -> 1, x[752] -> 0, x[753] -> 0, x[754] -> 1, x[755] -> 1, 
x[756] -> 0, x[757] -> 0, x[758] -> 0, x[759] -> 0, x[760] -> 0, 
x[761] -> 0, x[762] -> 1, x[763] -> 1, x[764] -> 1, x[765] -> 1, 
x[766] -> 0, x[767] -> 1, x[768] -> 0, x[769] -> 1, x[770] -> 1, 
x[771] -> 1, x[772] -> 1, x[773] -> 0, x[774] -> 1, x[775] -> 0, 
x[776] -> 0, x[777] -> 1, x[778] -> 1, x[779] -> 0, x[780] -> 1, 
x[781] -> 0, x[782] -> 0, x[783] -> 0, x[784] -> 1, x[785] -> 1, 
x[786] -> 0, x[787] -> 1, x[788] -> 1, x[789] -> 1, x[790] -> 0, 
x[791] -> 1, x[792] -> 1, x[793] -> 1, x[794] -> 0, x[795] -> 1, 
x[796] -> 0, x[797] -> 0, x[798] -> 1, x[799] -> 0, x[800] -> 1, 
x[801] -> 0, x[802] -> 0, x[803] -> 1, x[804] -> 1, x[805] -> 0, 
x[806] -> 1, x[807] -> 1, x[808] -> 0, x[809] -> 1, x[810] -> 0, 
x[811] -> 0, x[812] -> 1, x[813] -> 1, x[814] -> 1, x[815] -> 0, 
x[816] -> 0, x[817] -> 1, x[818] -> 0, x[819] -> 0, x[820] -> 0, 
x[821] -> 1, x[822] -> 1, x[823] -> 0, x[824] -> 0, x[825] -> 1, 
x[826] -> 0, x[827] -> 1, x[828] -> 0, x[829] -> 1, x[830] -> 1, 
x[831] -> 1, x[832] -> 0, x[833] -> 1, x[834] -> 1, x[835] -> 0, 
x[836] -> 1, x[837] -> 0, x[838] -> 0, x[839] -> 0, x[840] -> 1, 
x[841] -> 0, x[842] -> 1, x[843] -> 1, x[844] -> 0, x[845] -> 0, 
x[846] -> 1, x[847] -> 1, x[848] -> 1, x[849] -> 0, x[850] -> 0, 
x[851] -> 1, x[852] -> 0, x[853] -> 1, x[854] -> 1, x[855] -> 0, 
x[856] -> 1, x[857] -> 1, x[858] -> 0, x[859] -> 0, x[860] -> 0, 
x[861] -> 1, x[862] -> 1, x[863] -> 0, x[864] -> 1, x[865] -> 1, 
x[866] -> 0, x[867] -> 1, x[868] -> 1, x[869] -> 0, x[870] -> 0, 
x[871] -> 0, x[872] -> 1, x[873] -> 1, x[874] -> 0, x[875] -> 1, 
x[876] -> 1, x[877] -> 1, x[878] -> 1, x[879] -> 1, x[880] -> 1, 
x[881] -> 1, x[882] -> 0, x[883] -> 0, x[884] -> 1, x[885] -> 1, 
x[886] -> 0, x[887] -> 0, x[888] -> 1, x[889] -> 1, x[890] -> 0, 
x[891] -> 0, x[892] -> 0, x[893] -> 0, x[894] -> 0, x[895] -> 1, 
x[896] -> 0, x[897] -> 0, x[898] -> 1, x[899] -> 1, x[900] -> 1, 
x[901] -> 0, x[902] -> 1, x[903] -> 0, x[904] -> 0, x[905] -> 0, 
x[906] -> 1, x[907] -> 1, x[908] -> 1, x[909] -> 0, x[910] -> 0, 
x[911] -> 1, x[912] -> 1, x[913] -> 0, x[914] -> 0, x[915] -> 0, 
x[916] -> 0, x[917] -> 1, x[918] -> 0, x[919] -> 1, x[920] -> 0, 
x[921] -> 1, x[922] -> 0, x[923] -> 0, x[924] -> 1, x[925] -> 0, 
x[926] -> 1, x[927] -> 0, x[928] -> 0, x[929] -> 1, x[930] -> 0, 
x[931] -> 0, x[932] -> 0, x[933] -> 0, x[934] -> 0, x[935] -> 1, 
x[936] -> 0, x[937] -> 0, x[938] -> 0, x[939] -> 1, x[940] -> 0, 
x[941] -> 1, x[942] -> 0, x[943] -> 0, x[944] -> 1, x[945] -> 1, 
x[946] -> 0, x[947] -> 1, x[948] -> 1, x[949] -> 1, x[950] -> 1, 
x[951] -> 0, x[952] -> 0, x[953] -> 1, x[954] -> 0, x[955] -> 0, 
x[956] -> 1, x[957] -> 1, x[958] -> 0, x[959] -> 1, x[960] -> 0, 
x[961] -> 0, x[962] -> 1, x[963] -> 0, x[964] -> 0, x[965] -> 1, 
x[966] -> 1, x[967] -> 1, x[968] -> 0, x[969] -> 0, x[970] -> 0, 
x[971] -> 0, x[972] -> 0, x[973] -> 1, x[974] -> 0, x[975] -> 0, 
x[976] -> 0, x[977] -> 0, x[978] -> 0, x[979] -> 0, x[980] -> 1, 
x[981] -> 1, x[982] -> 0, x[983] -> 1, x[984] -> 1, x[985] -> 1, 
x[986] -> 1, x[987] -> 1, x[988] -> 0, x[989] -> 0, x[990] -> 0, 
x[991] -> 0, x[992] -> 0, x[993] -> 0, x[994] -> 1, x[995] -> 0, 
x[996] -> 0, x[997] -> 0, x[998] -> 0, x[999] -> 0, x[1000] -> 0, 
x[1001] -> 1, x[1002] -> 0, x[1003] -> 1, x[1004] -> 1, 
x[1005] -> 0, x[1006] -> 0, x[1007] -> 1, x[1008] -> 0, 
x[1009] -> 1, x[1010] -> 1, x[1011] -> 0, x[1012] -> 1, 
x[1013] -> 0, x[1014] -> 0, x[1015] -> 0, x[1016] -> 0, 
x[1017] -> 0, x[1018] -> 0, x[1019] -> 0, x[1020] -> 0, 
x[1021] -> 0, x[1022] -> 1, x[1023] -> 1, x[1024] -> 0}}, 0}}
```

Don't know exactly how, but all is done in one iteration. Think linear algebra methods are used.